# Unable to specify Resource Identifier for AWS::ApiGateway::Resource in Cloudformation Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I am using SAM to deploy a simple Hello world application. One with one API Endpoint, which will trigger a lambda function that returns the text hello world.
I have defined the following resources:

1. IAM Role so that APIGateway can invoke lambda functions.
2. AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
3. AWS::ApiGateway::Resource
4. AWS::ApiGateway::Method
5. AWS::Serverless::Function

Admittedly, I do not know the difference in functionality between 2. and 3. yet.

During `sam deploy` I see the following error.

```
ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS                              AWS::CloudFormation::Stack                        go-hello-world                                    The following resource(s) failed to create:     
                                                                                                                                                      [HelloWorldAPIResource,                         
                                                                                                                                                      HelloWorldFunctionRole]. Rollback requested by  
                                                                                                                                                      user.                                           
CREATE_FAILED                                     AWS::IAM::Role                                    HelloWorldFunctionRole                            Resource creation cancelled                     
CREATE_FAILED                                     AWS::ApiGateway::Resource                         HelloWorldAPIResource                             Resource handler returned message: "Invalid     
                                                                                                                                                      Resource identifier specified (Service:         
                                                                                                                                                      ApiGateway, Status Code: 404, Request ID:       
                                                                                                                                                      62f34d79-86ab-47fd-85b1-5fbb55071520, Extended  
                                                                                                                                                      Request ID: null)" (RequestToken:               
                                                                                                                                                      9633d7db-7b6d-881b-f54e-ca0114862fd8,           
                                                                                                                                                      HandlerErrorCode: NotFound)
```

Which means that the AWS::ApiGateway::Resource is not getting a valid reference to AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi.

Here is the relevant part from my `template.yml`

```
  HelloWorldAPI:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
    Properties: 
      Name: HelloWorldApi

  HelloWorldAPIResource:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Resource
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Ref HelloWorldAPI
      ParentId: "/"
      PathPart: hello
```

I am new to both CloudFormation and AWS in general, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you really want to create things that way? You could make your life easier, e.g. https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli-app-templates/blob/master/nodejs14.x/cookiecutter-aws-sam-hello-nodejs/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.project_name%7D%7D/template.yaml#L28

Comment: That might work for super simple APIs, but my Organisation has other conventions. :)

Comment: This should work. CF should be attempting to create the HelloWorldAPI resource in the stack before it attempts to create HelloWorldAPIResource. The dependency should be implied due to the Ref. Can you confirm that it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
 ParentId: !GetAtt HelloWorldAPI.RootResourceId
```